# Nextcloud: "No such file or directory" during install to MySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, nextcloud

I am trying to install NextCloud on my OpenWRT device; FriendlyElec NanoPi R6s (very, very beefy ARM SbC). So I installed MariaDB, PHP and Caddy. All of them work nicely, except: PHP can not connect to MariaDB, via `localhost`. And that breaks NextCloud's installer...

First, the error:

```
# sudo -u www ./occ maintenance:install --database mysql --database-name nextcloud --database-host localhost --database-port 3306 --database-user root --database-pass '<...>' --admin-user "IngwiePhoenix" --admin-pass '<...>'
The current PHP memory limit is below the recommended value of 512MB.
Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
Trace: #0 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/ConnectionAdapter.php(69): OC\DB\Exceptions\DbalException::wrap(Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Exception))
#1 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/MySqlTools.php(59): OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter->executeQuery('SELECT VERSION(...')
#2 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/MySqlTools.php(39): OC\DB\MySqlTools->isMariaDBWithLargePrefix(Object(OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter))
#3 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup/MySQL.php(47): OC\DB\MySqlTools->supports4ByteCharset(Object(OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter))
#4 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php(353): OC\Setup\MySQL->setupDatabase('IngwiePhoenix')
#5 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/core/Command/Maintenance/Install.php(105): OC\Setup->install(Array)
#6 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): OC\Core\Command\Maintenance\Install->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(OC\Core\Command\Maintenance\Install), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/Console/Application.php(213): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/console.php(100): OC\Console\Application->run()
#12 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/occ(11): require_once('/sdcard/srv/nex...')
#13 {main}

Previous: Doctrine\DBAL\Exception: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
Trace: #0 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php(1519): OC\DB\Connection->connect()
#1 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php(1041): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getWrappedConnection()
#2 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/Connection.php(261): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT VERSION(...', Array, Array, NULL)
#3 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/ConnectionAdapter.php(66): OC\DB\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT VERSION(...', Array, Array)
#4 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/MySqlTools.php(59): OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter->executeQuery('SELECT VERSION(...')
#5 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/MySqlTools.php(39): OC\DB\MySqlTools->isMariaDBWithLargePrefix(Object(OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter))
#6 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup/MySQL.php(47): OC\DB\MySqlTools->supports4ByteCharset(Object(OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter))
#7 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/Setup.php(353): OC\Setup\MySQL->setupDatabase('IngwiePhoenix')
#8 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/core/Command/Maintenance/Install.php(105): OC\Setup->install(Array)
#9 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): OC\Core\Command\Maintenance\Install->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(OC\Core\Command\Maintenance\Install), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/lib/private/Console/Application.php(213): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/console.php(100): OC\Console\Application->run()
#15 /sdcard/srv/nextcloud/occ(11): require_once('/sdcard/srv/nex...')
#16 {main}
```

Then, my MariaDB config:

```
# cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/50-server.cnf | grep bind
bind-address    = localhost
```

And the verification:

```
# netstat -lntu | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::1:3306                :::*                    LISTEN
```

The MariaDB logs also indicate a successful start:

```
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using ARMv8 crc32 + pmull instructions
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Warning] mysqld: io_uring_queue_init() failed with errno 2
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Warning] InnoDB: liburing disabled: falling back to innodb_use_native_aio=OFF
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 67108864, chunk size = 67108864
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.10 started; log sequence number 42510; transaction id 14
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /srv/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 221211 14:13:03
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::1'.
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2022-12-11 14:13:03 0 [Note] /usr/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.6.10-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution

==> /var/log/mysql/mysql.log <==
/usr/bin/mysqld, Version: 10.6.10-MariaDB-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: (null)
Time                Id Command  Argument
```

And, for good meassure:

```
# cat /etc/php.ini | grep mysql
;[mysql]
mysql.default_socket = "/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock"
mysqli.default_socket = "/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock"
mysqlnd.default_socket = "/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

It's all there, its all aligned - it should just /work/. But for one reason or another, NextCloud just refuses to connect and after digging through MariaDB configs and PHP FPM configs, I am truely out of ideas and options...

Comment: The location of unix_socket in php.ini and server configuration differ.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I was close. There is one more location where one would have to specify the default socket:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket = "/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

So, the full loadout is:

```
mysql.default_socket = "/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock"
mysqli.default_socket = "/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock"
mysqlnd.default_socket = "/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock"
pdo_mysql.default_socket = "/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Hope this eventually helps someone. Should cover all cases. After that, Nextcloud connected and installed properly :)

Side-note: Make sure the MySQL user that you use for initial setup has `GRANT OPTIONS`. Otherwise, It will fail regardless.